# "Unknown" driver in Windows Assessment and Deployment Tool Kit

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an issue with high ram usage. I have 16 GB RAM and its 7 GB is consuming. Normally this should be 3 GB. I detect this is a driver problem so I scan all drives with Windows Assessment and Deployment Tool Kit. I found out one driver is consuming 4 GB RAM. But its name is "Unknown". How can I find this driver's name? Thanks in advance. Here is a picture:

[image]